# laravel 9 crud user hash password

Tags: php, laravel

I made a crud user but I have a problem with the password hashing.

```
 @extends('superadmin.layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- left column -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- general form elements -->
            <div class="card card-primary">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="card-title">New User</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <!-- form start -->
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('user.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" required>
                        </div>
                        @error('name')
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                        </div>
                        @enderror

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputFile">Image</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="custom-file">
                                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="Image" name="image" required>
                                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @error('image')
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                        </div>
                        @enderror

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Secret word</label>
                            <input id="secretword" type="text" class="form-control @error('secretword') is-invalid @enderror" name="secretword" value="{{ old('secretword') }}" required autocomplete="secretword" autofocus>
                        </div>
                        @error('secretword')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @enderror

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Telegram</label>
                            <input id="telegram" type="text" class="form-control @error('telegram') is-invalid @enderror" name="telegram" value="{{ old('telegram') }}" required autocomplete="telegram" autofocus>
                        </div>
                        @error('telegram')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @enderror

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">
                        </div>
                        @error('email')
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                        </div>
                        @enderror

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Password') }}</label>
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">
                        </div> 
                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                        

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                        </div>
            </div>

            <!-- /.card-body -->
            <div class="card-footer pt-0">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!--/.col (right) -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
</div>
@endsection
```

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::latest()->paginate(50);



        return view('superadmin.user.index', compact('users'))

            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $usersall = User::all();
        return view('superadmin.user.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'secretword' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();



        if ($image = $request->file('image')) {

            $destinationPath = public_path('images/');


            $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $image->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);

            $input['image'] = "$profileImage";
        }

        User::create($input);

        return redirect()->route('user.index')
            ->with('success', 'User created');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        return view('superadmin.user.edit', compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'telegram' => 'required',
            'secretword' => 'required',
        ]);
        $input = $request->all();
  
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->telegram = $request->telegram;
        $user->secretword = $request->secretword;
        $user->save();
        return redirect()->route('user.index')->with('success','User updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $users = User::find($id);
        $users->delete();
        return redirect()->route('user.index')->with('success', 'Utilisateur supprime');
    }
}
```

```
 <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Qirolab\Laravel\Reactions\Traits\Reacts;
use Qirolab\Laravel\Reactions\Contracts\ReactsInterface;

class User extends Authenticatable implements ReactsInterface
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, Reacts;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'secretword',
        'image',
        'telegram',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(Role::class)
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\User')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function authorizeRoles($roles)
    {
        if ($this->hasAnyRole($roles)) {
            return true;
        }
        abort(401, 'This action is unauthorized.');
    }

    public function hasAnyRole($roles)
    {
        if (is_array($roles)) {
            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->hasRole($roles)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        if ($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

I would like to make a hash of the password but I can't. I saw in the documentation that it is necessary to do Hash::make() but I don't understand where I have to do this. Could someone put me the line of code that needs to be done for hash and or tell me where I need to put it? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A call to `$request->validate()` returns an `array` of validated data. So what you can do is save that return value to a variable, then access the `password` element on the `array` in order to hash it before providing everything to your `User::create()` method.

```
$validated = $request->validate([
    'name' => 'required',
    'secretword' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required',
    'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
]);

$validated['password'] = Hash::make($validated['password']);

User::create($validated);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer crud for user worked, i have added this : $validated['password'] = Hash::make($validated['password']); and all worked good thank very much

Answer (score 1):

try with this method bcrypt function is in laravel that give you a hash password easly.

```
  $fields = $request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|string',
    'email' => 'required|string|unique:users,email',
    'password' => 'required|string|confirmed'
]);

   $user = User::create([
    'name'=>$fields['name'],
    'email' => $fields['email'],
    'password' =>bcrypt($fields['password'])
]);
```